# populate word template (with repeat) from excel

Tags: excel, ms-word

I have data in an Excel spreadsheet that I want to include in a report in Word.

In Excel, one line = one data entry.
In Word, each line will result in a layout block.

There are many lines, I want to define the template once and have whatever function imports from Excel duplicate it as often as necessary.

Mailmerge, AFAIK, creates seperate documents. That is **not** what I need, I need multiple blocks within one document.

Couldn't find a solution so far, everything points me to Mailmerge.

---

As requested, an example:

#### In Excel:

```
TEST - RESULT - REASON - COMMENT
Check A - failed - missing a foo - install a foo next time
Check B - success - ok - worked as designed
Check C - success - mostly ok - worked, but can be improved
```

#### In Word:

```
Test Report

Check Number: Check A
Check Result: failed (missing a foo)
Comment: install a foo next time
```

You get the idea. The actual template is not so simple, but the main idea is that fields are not identical to lines - there can be multiple fields in the same line, in different places around the template, etc.

Comment: Can you give an example of your data and what you need it to look like when it's done?  Could this be compared to printing address labels? (ie., a small form that repeats on the same page multiple times.)

Comment: Yes, a small form that repeats on the same page multiple times is exactly what I need. There will be about 3-4 forms per page, depending on how long the text in certain fields is (e.g. comment fields)

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you're not finished with Mail Merge yet!

`multiple blocks within one document` :

[image: img]

It's the same idea as labels... you're just not printing them onto labels, and you're making up a custo size and layout.

- Office.com : **[Create and print labels using mail merge](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-and-print-labels-using-mail-merge-276a2cd1-74d2-43d0-ab5a-b90460358ad5)**

More information, Google "word labels from excel data"...

Comment: Since the answer to this is non-programming, and you have the rep, be good to "close" with off-topic, other site, Super User, which will migrate the entire discussion if enough vote that way?

Comment: @CindyMeister Done. Question for you re: [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49648805/8112776)...  do you know what happens if votes are split on which site to migrate to?

Comment: Ah, those first two don't migrate - the one WAY down the list, near the bottom, migrates. The others only close.