# Microsoft SQL Server copy paste results to excel not working

Tags: excel, ssms

We have a remote connect to Microsoft SQL Server studio, there are 4 remote connections we could get assigned. Now on 2 of these servers, it allows us to copy and paste the results(grid) to excel. However, on the other 2 servers, it won't allow us to copy/paste at all.

Is there permissions within the database that would stop us or is it down to the remote connection?

Comment: I think it would be due to the connection configurations, but not completely sure. This question probably belongs to Server fault or Super user.

Comment: Check the sharing options on your rdp. Maybe Google share clipboard across rdp. Update the question if that's not it

Comment: Agreed. If 2 servers are working and 2 aren't, this is a server setup issue, not a programming issue.

Comment: Are you using ctrl+V to paste?  Try right-click paste (from the context menu).

Comment: Also if you are using ctrl+V, you could use the context menu to save the results to a csv and use.

Answer (score 0):

Use Task Manager to 'End task' on rdpclip.exe on the remote machine.

Then restart it using a Command Prompt by typing `rdpclip`

[image]